# d3.js change format of price and date

Tags: d3.js, crossfilter, dc.js

I want to change date and number format in d3.js.

I have use below code to generate chart.

```
collectionRate.width(940)
    .height(250)
    .dimension(collectionRateValue)
    .group(collectionRateValueGroup_payment, "Payment")
    //.stack(collectionRateValueGroup_adj, "count")
    .stack(collectionRateValueGroup_ar_bal, "charge amt")
    .title(function(d) {
        return  ": ";
    })
    .renderTitle(true)
    .transitionDuration(1500)
    .margins({
        top: 10, 
        right: 50, 
        bottom: 30, 
        left: 70
    })
    .centerBar(true)
    .gap(10)
    .xAxisPadding(500)
    .xUnits(d3.time.months)
    .label(function(d){
        return "d.key";
    })
    .round(d3.time.month.round)
    .x(d3.time.scale().domain([new Date(2012, 11, 1), new Date(2013, 12, 31)]))
    //.x(d3.scale.linear().domain([-1, 10000]))
    .legend(dc.legend().x(750).y(0))
    .elasticY(true)


    dc.renderAll();
    dc.redrawAll();
    d3.select("#dc-pie-graph > svg > g").attr("transform", "translate(100,100)");
```

Result of code is below.

[image: d3.js]

Now, what i want
I want to change Y-axis value format 500,000 To 50K, same as other.
currently, X-axis value is January, February.... I want to change that to Jan-13.

I have tried but i can't success to change format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`.tickFormat()` function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-tickFormat) to do this, e.g. for the x axis:

```
.xAxis().tickFormat(d3.time.format("%b-%d"));
```

You are currently rounding to whole months (`.round(d3.time.month.round)`), which you may want to remove for this. For the y axis, it would look something like this:

```
.yAxis().tickFormat(d3.format(",.0s"));
```